# Show that angle that the photon is deflected is given by $2\sin^2\left(\frac12\theta\right)=\frac{mc}q-\frac{mc}p$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, photons, momentum

> A photon collides with an electron of rest mass $m$ that is initially
>   at rest in the laboratory frame. Show that the angle $\theta$ by which
>   the photon is deflected is related to the magnitudes $p$ and $q$ of
>   its initial and final momenta by
>   $$2\sin^2\left(\frac12\theta\right)=\frac{mc}q-\frac{mc}p$$

I have that $\mathbf{p}=\frac Ec\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \mathbf{\hat n}\end{pmatrix}$ and the initial momentum of the electron being $\begin{pmatrix} mc \\ \mathbf{0}\end{pmatrix}$.

I think we also have that $\mathbf{q}=\frac Ec\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \mathbf{\hat n'}\end{pmatrix}$ where $\mathbf{\hat n'}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta \\ \sin\theta \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and it looks to me that we'll somehow compare the $x$-components but other than that I don't see how to use any of this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial and final 4-momentum's are:
$$
\begin{align}
p_I &= \left(p+mc,p{\bf \hat n}\right)\\
p_F &= \left(q+\gamma mc,q{\bf \hat n}'+\gamma m {\bf v}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
Conservation of 4-momentum leads to:
$$
\begin{align}
p+mc &= q + \gamma mc\\
p\cos \theta &= q + \gamma m{\bf v\cdot\hat n'}
\end{align}
$$
Conservation of total mass leads to:
$$
p = \gamma q(1 - \frac{1}{c}{\bf v\cdot\hat n'})
$$
Solving these by eliminating $\gamma$ and ${\bf v\cdot\hat n'}$ will get you your desired result.

Comment: Hello and thanks. I'm probably being an idiot here but I don't see where the $p=\gamma q(1-\frac 1c\mathbf{v\cdot \hat n'})$ has come from, thanks for your answer so far

Comment: The total mass of the system being conserved, $p^I_{\mu}p_I^\mu=p^F_{\mu}p_F^\mu$

Comment: Ok thanks, I have not seen that or the notation before. I am very thankful for your answer but I am wondering if there is another way to get that equation, conservation of energy perhaps?

Comment: Conservation of energy is the first of the three equations. Conservation of 3-momentum is the second equation. The third equation is the conservation of relativistic mass. You need all three since you have three variables: $\theta, {\bf v\cdot\hat n'},$ and $|{\bf v}|$.

Comment: Ok yeah silly me, thanks. This is interesting as I don't think I'm expected to use this. Thanks again but could you possibly define $p_{\mu}^I$ for me? I'm assuming $p_I^{\mu}$ is the $\mu^{th}$ component of $p_I$. thanks

Comment: That is correct. The full dot product there, using the Einstein summation convention reads:
$$
p^I_\mu p_I^\mu = \eta_{\mu\nu}p_I^\mu p_I^\nu
$$
where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it turns out that as the $3$-momentum form a closed triangle  the cosine rule together with energy conservation is enough to get the result

Comment: Yup, that works as well. The conservation of 3-momentum gives 2 constraints (since the collision is confined to a plane). I only wrote one of the constraints, and then used CoRM to close the set. The Law of Cosines is just the other constraint coming from Co3M. You can see this by writing $\gamma m {\bf v} = p{\bf n}-q{\bf n'}$ and taking the inner product of the equation with itself. It's nice to see that in either case we have consistency. Good luck!